# How to define two foreign keys that are not composite with Data Annotations in database first EF?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In SQL, I have a table with two columns that both map to the same primary key in another table.  The easiest way to explain is using the table constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[sls_n_Promotion]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_SlsPromotion_SlsPromotionTradeSpendType] FOREIGN KEY([TradeSpendID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[sls_a_PromotionTradeSpendType] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[sls_n_Promotion] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_SlsPromotion_SlsPromotionTradeSpendType]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[sls_n_Promotion]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_SlsPromotion_SlsPromotionTradeSpendType2] FOREIGN KEY([TradeSpendSubID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[sls_a_PromotionTradeSpendType] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[sls_n_Promotion] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_SlsPromotion_SlsPromotionTradeSpendType2]
GO
```

I'm using database first, and I have created `Promotion.partial.cs`.  In this partial class, I'm struggling to get the Data Attributes set correctly for 'TradeSpendID' and 'TradeSpendSubID'.  This is what I currently have:

```
[Display(Name="Trade Spend Type")]
[Column("TradeSpendID")]
[ForeignKey("PromotionTradeSpendType")]
int? TradeSpendId { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Trade Spend Sub Type")]
[Column("TradeSpendSubID")]
[ForeignKey("PromotionTradeSpendType")]
int? TradeSpendSubId { get; set; }
```

When I go to create a Controller using scaffolding, I get the error:

> Unable to determine a composite foreign key ordering for foreign key
>   on type...

This isn't a composite foreign key.

**Question:**
**How do I use Data Attributes for the foreign keys on those 2 properties?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be two Navigation Properties.  EG

```
[Display(Name="Trade Spend Type")]
[Column("TradeSpendID")]
[ForeignKey("PromotionTradeSpendType")]
public int? TradeSpendId { get; set; }
public virtual PromotionTradeSpendType PromotionTradeSpendType { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Trade Spend Sub Type")]
[Column("TradeSpendSubID")]
[ForeignKey("PromotionTradeSpendSubType")]
public int? TradeSpendSubId { get; set; }
public virtual PromotionTradeSpendType PromotionTradeSpendSubType { get; set; }
```